# New to SQL servers, wanting to schedule table / data moves every X hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have looked at a few stackoverflow forum posts but nothing fits (or atleast I dont think so) what I need help with.

I'm looking for general advise, my company has 'tasked' me to look at moving some data from tables stored in our parent companies databases into a database of our own that has all the information we need in one place.

For instance if we want information that related to one thing, we may have to pull data from several different databases. I think I can get my head around the moving of the data and create a sql query to do it, however we're currently using SQL express as our SQL db (the company is more than happy to buy/create a SQL server but as far as we can see SQL express does what we need it too (feel free to correct me)).

I need to look at scheduling the data move for every hour or few hours to keep the data 'up to date' for when reports are generated using the data.

I have looked at a few programs but the as the queries and the database is on a server 2008 r2 system some of the 'programs' don't like it as they were last updated pre 2010 etc. I have also installed SQL management suite 2012 due to SQL server agent but I cant even get that worked (Service is enabled and I have restarted the DB just still nothing within suite).

I'm not looking (however happy to take the help) for a 'Do this and that and that' type reply but more than happy to accept that amount of help but if you guys / gals can point me in the right direction.

Summary:

-Combining data already on databases from our parent company into a table / DB of our own making
-Currently using SQL Express but willing to upgrade to something else that does the job
-Schedule the data moves for every X hours (Windows scheduling?)
-automating the entire thing so don't have to manually do the moves.

Help on any of the points above would be greatly appreciated and I would 'love you long time' for the help.

JB

Comment: I hardly ever use SQL Server Express, but IIRC, one of its restrictions is that it doesn't have a SQL Agent.

Comment: Yep, this link confirms, no SQL Agent for Express Edition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express#Capabilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of limitations for SQL Express.  One of them is that SQL Agent is not supported.  SSIS like SQL Agent is not supported.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Do not fret, you can always schedule a job with Windows Scheduler.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

As for moving the data, it is up to you to select a solution.

1 - Write a **PowerShell** application to perform the Extract, Translate, and Load (ETL).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281945(v=sql.105).aspx

2 - Use the **SQLCMD** to perform logic like calling stored procedures.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

3 - Use **BCP** to dump and load data.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1245
http://craftydba.com/?p=1255
http://craftydba.com/?p=1584
http://craftydba.com/?p=1690

It is funny how youngsters think they need to spend a-lot of $ to create a solution for a business.

However, Microsoft does supply you with a-lot of free tools.

You just have to put them together for a solution.

PS: I remember about 10 years ago I created a custom ETL solution using VBSCRIPT.  Unlike power shell, it is installed on old and new programs.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at [Integartion Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993%28v=sql.105%29.ASPX#SSIS), which is not available for Express Edition. Have a look at this article to get started with [SSIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441678/Getting-Started-With-SSIS-Script-transforms).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a console application which executes that particular stored procedure which handles your logic. ( http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/basics-stored-procedures-net )

Of course using SSIS is much easier but it's not available in SQL Server Express Edition.